# how to read a int[] chunk by chunk

Tags: java, arrays, chunked

Suppose an int[] is passed in, and I have function f(int[] array), if I don't know the length of array, how can I execute it chunk by chunk? or is there any better way do it? Thanks

Comment: You do know the length of the array, it is `array.length` - Maybe you mean "How many elements were initialized with a different value then 0?"

Comment: Is there any change the size of array is larger than Integer.Max_VALUE?

Comment: The size of the array cannot be bigger then `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, you can get the length of the array from the array, simply by using:

```
int theArrayLength = array.length;
```

Comment: Is there any change the size of array is larger than Integer.Max_VALUE?

Comment: @Jeffrey No. Since you index arrays by using ints that'd be somewhat useless ;)

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "execute it" and "chunk by chunk"? You can always iterate over the array using an index.

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  bar(array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Check if the array is `null`, and if so, throw an exception (e.g. `IllegalArgumentException`)
2. Use enhanced for-loop

## Example -

```
void f(int[] array){
    if(array == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    for(int arrayItem : array){
        // iterate through array chunk-by-chunk
    }
}
```

Using this approach, you can iterate through the array chunk-by-chunk without explicitly knowing the length of the array.

Answer (score 1):

doesn't java also know the arraya.length ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the length of any array in Java by doing

```
array.length
```